# What is the meaning of 一草一木 here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

宝钗说：“这么说，我也是和你一样的。”

林黛玉 did not agree. Part of what she said is:

我是一无所有，吃穿用度，一草一木，都和他们家的姑娘一样，那些小人岂有不多嫌的。

What does she mean with “一草一木”？

Answer (score 5):

一草一木 is an idiom, originating from [*Book of the later Han*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Later_Han):

> 《後漢書・應劭傳》：「春**一草**枯則為災，秋**一木**華亦為異。」
>
> *In spring, a single blade of grass that withers heralds disaster; in autumn, a single tree that flourishes is unnatural.*
>
> That is, every small detail or single thing out of place suggests unnatural occurrences.

This was later shortened to 一草一木, meaning *every small/single thing*.

> 我是一無所有，吃穿用度，一草一木，皆是和他們家的姑娘一樣...
>
> *I have nothing at all; everything I use - what I'm eating or wearing, every single thing - are the same as the girls of that family...*

Answer (score 4):

She means that every small thing she is provided with, including food and daily necessities, are essentially the same with girls of this family.
“一草一木”  here means "every small thing".

Answer (score 2):

*ABC* defines **一草一木** as:

> every blade of grass and every tree/bush; every little thing

*KEY* also writes:

> "every blade of grass and every tree"—every bit of property

So, every little thing + every bit of property would fit your above sentence okay.